menu hamburguesa html, css, vanilla JS
tengo un menú hamburguesa, hecho con HTML, CSS y JS, que funciona bien, le agregue una clase y (con JS) cada vez que clickeo el menú hamburguesa se despliega el menú con la animación y aparece la imagen (X) para cerrar, pero no logro hacer que cuando clickeo esa X el menú tenga la misma animación para irse, no se si debería separar el logo y el menú en un div aparte, porque ambos están en el .main_nav, intente también aplicarles una animación distinta dependiendo de que imagen se clickeaba.
Dejo el código abajo:


let menuHamburguer = document.querySelector(".nav_hamburguer"),
  main = document.querySelector(".main"),
  iconClose = document.querySelector(".icon_close"),
  main_nav = document.querySelector(".main_nav");

menuHamburguer.addEventListener("click", () => {
  main.classList.toggle("open_menu");
});

iconClose.addEventListener("click", () => {
  main.classList.remove("open_menu");
});
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

.main {
  max-width: 1600px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(5, max-content) / 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "main" "shop" "image1" "about" "image2";
}

.main_hero {
  min-height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  grid-area: main;
}

.background-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

.backgrounds-mobile {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.backgrounds-desktop {
  display: none;
}

.background-img {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 3/1;
}

.main_nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/* STYLE FOR MENU HAMBURGUER*/

main.open_menu {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
}

main.open_menu .main_hero .main_logo,
main.open_menu .main_hero .main_nav .nav_hamburguer {
  display: none;
}

main.open_menu .main_hero .main_nav {
  background-color: var(--White);
  width: 100%;
  animation: showMenu 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes menuClose {
  from {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  to {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 0);
  }
}

@keyframes showMenu {
  from {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 0);
  }
  to {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
}

main.open_menu .main_hero .main_nav .main_links {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

main.open_menu .main_hero .main_nav .main_links .main_list {
  padding-left: 1.4rem;
}

main.open_menu .main_hero .main_nav .main_links .main_list .main_link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--Black);
  font-family: "League Spartan", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

main.open_menu .main_hero .container_logo_menu .icon_close {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

main.open_menu .main_hero .background-container .backgrounds img {
  opacity: var(--opacity);
  filter: var(--brightness);
}

main.open_menu .main_bg_second {
  opacity: var(--opacity);
  filter: var(--brightness);
}

main.open_menu .main_controls {
  filter: brightness(0.2);
  cursor: none;
}

main.open_menu .container_logo_menu .icon_close {
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}
<main class="main">
  <!--  SECTION MAIN -->
  <section class="main_hero">
    <div class="background-container">
      <div class="backgrounds-mobile">
        <img src="images/mobile-image-hero-1.jpg" alt="" class="background-img" />
        <img src="images/mobile-image-hero-2.jpg" alt="" class="background-img" />
        <img src="images/mobile-image-hero-3.jpg" alt="" class="background-img" />
      </div>

      <div class="backgrounds-desktop">
        <img src="images/desktop-image-hero-1.jpg" alt="" class="background-img" />
        <img src="images/desktop-image-hero-2.jpg" alt="" class="background-img" />
        <img src="images/desktop-image-hero-3.jpg" alt="" class="background-img" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container_logo_menu">
      <svg class="nav_hamburguer" width="20" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path
                  d="M20 12v2H0v-2h20zm0-6v2H0V6h20zm0-6v2H0V0h20z"
                  fill="hsl(0, 0%, 100%)"
                  fill-rule="evenodd"
                />
              </svg>

      <svg class="icon_close" width="16" height="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path
                  d="M14.364.222l1.414 1.414L9.414 8l6.364 6.364-1.414 1.414L8 9.414l-6.364 6.364-1.414-1.414L6.586 8 .222 1.636 1.636.222 8 6.586 14.364.222z"
                  fill="#a1a1a1"
                  fill-rule="evenodd"
                  opacity="1"
                />
              </svg>

      <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="" class="main_logo" />
    </div>

    <nav class="main_nav container">
      <ul class="main_links">
        <ol class="main_list">
          <a href="#" class="main_link">home</a>
        </ol>

        <ol class="main_list">
          <a href="#" class="main_link">shop</a>
        </ol>

        <ol class="main_list">
          <a href="#" class="main_link">about</a>
        </ol>

        <ol class="main_list">
          <a href="#" class="main_link">contact</a>
        </ol>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>




Por favor, comparta el código JavaScript.

El JS esta al final @cardosource

Con el código provisto, no logro entender la animación que buscas realizar. Actualmente el código funciona, la hamburguesa abre y cierra, y la X cierra solamente. Hay manera de que realices un [mre] de prueba ?? Algo visual que corra acá por ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/

Voy a explicar en modo genérico, porque creo es más útil para otros lectores:
Existen al menos 2 formas de animar:

Con transiciones: Es más simple y menos versátil. Con solo agregar/quitar una clase puedes animar la entrada/salida de un elemento
Con animaciones: Es algo "más complejo", y para animar una entrada/salida necesitas 2 clases, en tu caso una "open" y otra "close"

Vamos con esta última forma: Aquí puedes generar 2 keyframes de animacion: La primera con los valores de "open" y la segunda sería lo inverso para el "close"
Existe otra alternativa, que es reversar la primera animación. Para esto es necesario utilizar un truco: Debemos hacer que el navegador vuelva reestablecer la animación para esto quitamos las clases (open y close) solicitamos algo como el offsetWidth, lo cual obliga al navegador a obtener un valor del ancho, por lo que ejecuta el cambio render visual volviendo el play-state al valor inicial (ya que no tiene las clases).
Por último, mencionar, que antes había un problema al mostrar/esconder elementos que inician como ocultos (el típico modal). Ya que se utiliza display:none, entonces para ocultar había que utilizar código javascript que esperara que la animación finalizara y volver el elemento nuevamente a display:none. Hoy las animaciones permiten modificar la propiedad display asi que o hay problema. Para demostrarlo, en el ejemplo, agrego un cuadrado azul, y se ve claramente que cuando la animación del cuadrado rojo termina, el azul ocupa su lugar.


function mostrar(){
 resetAnimation(algo)
  algo.classList.add("open");
}

function esconder(){
  resetAnimation(algo)
  algo.classList.add("close");
}

function resetAnimation(el){
   el.classList.remove('open','close');
   return el.offsetWidth;
}
#algo{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:red;
   display:none;
}

#algo.open{
  display:block;
  animation: 2s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards running ejemploAnimacion;
}

#algo.close{
  display:block;
  animation: 2s  ease-in 0s 1 reverse forwards running ejemploAnimacion;
}

@keyframes ejemploAnimacion {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    display:none;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#otro{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:blue;
}
<button onclick="mostrar()">mostrar</button>
<button onclick="esconder()">esconder</button>

<div id="algo"></div>
<div id="otro"></div>




Resumen:

Se necesitan 2 clases:

Open: Con la animación en normal
Close: Con la animación en reverse


Una función que resetee la animación


Como recomendación final, averigua sobre el elemento <dialog> yo lo he utilizado para menús con bastantes buenos resultados
